# Find numbers on a string and order by them

Tags: php, string, numbers

I have this string

```
$s = "red2 blue5 black4 green1 gold3";
```

I need to order by the number, but can show the numbers.
Numbers will always appears at the end of the word.
the result should be like:

```
$s = "green red gold black blue";
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your solution at the moment? Don't understand how the output should be looked like

Comment: You need the number and the word, or just order the numbers? Also is the number always last or can be anywhere in string?

Comment: You need to use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = "red2 blue5 black4 green1 gold3";
$a=[];
preg_replace_callback('/[a-z0-9]+/',function($m) use (&$a){
    $a[(int)ltrim($m[0],'a..z')] = rtrim($m[0],'0..9');
},$s);
ksort($a);
print " Version A: ".implode(' ',$a);

$a=[];
foreach(explode(' ',$s) as $m){
    $a[(int)ltrim($m,'a..z')] = rtrim($m,'0..9');
}
ksort($a);
print " Version B: ".implode(' ',$a);

preg_match_all("/([a-z0-9]+)/",$s,$m);
foreach($m[1] as $i){
    $a[(int)substr($i,-1,1)] = rtrim($i,'0..9');
}
ksort($a);
print " Version C: ".implode(' ',$a);
```

Use one of them, but also try to understand whats going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Does it always follow this pattern - separated by spaces?

I would break down the problem as such:

1. I would first start with parsing the string into an array where the key is the number and the value is the word. You can achieve this with a combination of [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all) and [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine)
2. Then you [could use `ksort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) in order to sort by the keys we set with the previous step.
3. Finally, if you wish to return your result as a string, [you could `implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the resulting array, separating by spaces again.

An example solution could then be:

```php
<?php

$x = "red2 blue5 black4 green1 gold3";

function sortNumberedWords(string $input) {
    preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)/', $input, $splitResults);
    $combined = array_combine($splitResults[2], $splitResults[1]);

    ksort($combined);

    return implode(' ', $combined);
}

echo sortNumberedStrings($x);
```

[The regex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) I'm using here matches two seperate groups (indicated by the brackets):

1. The first group is any length of a string of characters `a-z` (or capitalised). Its worth noting this only works on the latin alphabet; it won't match ö, for example.
2. The second group matches any length of a string of numbers that appears directly after that string of characters.

The results of these matches are stored in `$splitResults`, which will be an array of 3 elements:

1. `[0]` A combined list of all the matches.
2. `[1]` A list of all the matches of group 1.
3. `[2]` A list of all the matches of group 2.

We use `array_combine` to then combine these into a single associative array. We wish for group 2 to act as the 'key' and group 1 to act as the 'value'.

Finally, we sort by the key, and then implode it back into a string.